# jQuery.load doesn't load in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ftp

At first, jQuery loads correctly in localhost(XAMPP) but it doesn't load anything when opened on ftp (using FileZilla to upload to ftp).

**Update (edited)** : It works correctly only in Firefox. The symptom that firefox has different from other browsers is, it asks multiple permissions to fill ID and password before I can reach the first index site while other ask only 1 time.

Here is my code where it should load.

HTML :

```
<button onclick="setLayout('layout2.html');">Layout2 F</button>
<div id="layout-grid"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
function setLayout(selectedLayout) {
     $("#layout-grid").load("custom/layout/layout2.html");
}
```

I tried change to .txt and absolute url `ftp.77-house.com:2002/custom/layout/layout2.html` but still doesn't work. No error is shown in console after all. What am I missing here ? Is it about something get blocked for security or something in addition blocking it from loading external ftp ?

Thank you in advice ! Hope you can help my first time using ftp.

Comment: did you try giving absolute url ?

Comment: I tried using absolute ftp, still doesn't work, I will edit question for this. It can load by passing to url, but won't load using jQuery.load.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a path/url problem.

Try this:

```
$("#layout-grid").load("http://yoursite/custom/layout/layout1.html");
```

Comment: I tried it with several ways with absulute ftp link but it is still doesn't work. It loads correctly using copy-paste url to the browser, but won't load when using jQuery.load

Comment: I had updated the clue, it loads correctly only in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There might be couple things you need to check. First make sure your url is correct. Second, check CHMOD for files that you want to access. Somehow, they might be restricted.Set permissions correctly then you will be fine

Comment: I had updated the clue. It works only in firefox. Please recheck to see the symptom. Many thanks !